# Are narcissist and vainglorious the same?

Tags: word-choice

I was looking up the dictionary to find a word for a person who admires himself a lot like his thoughts or appearance. I came up with two words ,narcissist and vainglorious. Both describe a person who excessively self admires....
My question is what is the difference between narcissist and vainglorious?

Comment: *Narcissist* is a noun, *vainglorious* is an adjective. They can't really be conformed, because the noun form of *vainglorious* is *vainglory*, which, unlike *narcissist*, is not a type of person. You would at least use these words in different contexts, performing different functions.

Comment: @Robusto *Narcissistic* is an adjective.

Comment: @Hot: Obviously.